# I cannot run ASP.NET Projects anymore

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis-express

I try to develop a ASP.NET Application. But I cannot run it anymore.
When I try to run it, Visual Studio (2013 and 2015) is starting InternetExplorer (I have also tested other browsers) and then it is waiting ... and never ends waiting:

[image: IE is waiting ...]

IIS Express (V 10.0.10557.1000) is started in the try but the website will never be load in the Browser.

[image: IIS is started ...]

Does someone know this problem and can help me with a solution?

Comment: Once the project's running, does Debug->Break All  show you which code is currently executing?

Comment: No. But now, I have seen, that when I downgrade to IIS Express 8.0 all is working great. It seems, that the Problem is related to the Version 10 of IIS Express ...

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with a new project? Also, did you change your firewall and anti-virus software?

Comment: Is there any reason not use "normal" IIS? It is closer to the production environment in terms of settings, behavior etc.